# Eeeek! Why do we tolerate "Eeeek!" in question titles?

Tags: discussion, reputation, title, memes

Recently, I have noticed some question titles beginning with "Eeeek!" It's now become kind of a meme here in meta, but why are we tolerating this?

Maybe I'm missing something, but it's not better than "Urgent! Please help!"

Comment: (-1) "Eeeek" should only have three lower-case e's.

Comment: @mmyers - fixed that for you.

Comment: Fixed that for *you*

Comment: @mmyers it's caused by my spellchecker, in french there's four lower-case e's.

Comment: @Richard - thanks. I think we have a new meme now.

Comment: @status, "now"? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/83625#83625

Comment: Because the horse is still breathing. Won't be much longer.

Comment: @Pop - I was referring to Richard's edit (Urgent! Please help! Why we tolerate those Eeeek in question title). But DavRob60 killed it.

Comment: Eeeek! What is a meme anyway? (From the question pointed by @Popular Demand: The term "Internet Meme" is used to describe a catchphrase or concept that spreads quickly from person to person via the Internet -- see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme_%28Internet%29 for more details)

Comment: Today isn't Friday, but it will have to do. It's been way too long since the last Friday in Meta-Land. And April Fools doesn't count.

Comment: @status-declined I smashed the egg before the monster hatch.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To seriously answer (even though it's crying for joke answers), the Meta community does an awesome job of giving support to users who have questions, problems, ideas, and so on. This isn't always easy, since you're often dealing with trolls, cluelessness, language barriers, and "where did my rep go" questions.

Memes like the "Eeeek!" thing give Meta a certain personality and are a not-so-small part of controlling the insanity and keeping the whole thing a bit light-hearted. After all, most of the people here don't get paid, even though they do tons of work to keep Meta organized and be helpful to others, and a "keep your humor at home" policy would surely not help in keeping everyone motivated.

In the past, it has been proven that the Meta community is actually also pretty good at [making sure that the funny doesn't get out of hand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75715/why-isnt-meta-funny-anymore).

Comment: *trolls, cluelessness, language barriers, and "where did my rep go"* -- Yes, but out of the 20,000+ questions on meta, I bet you can't name more than 15,000 that fall into any of those categories.

Comment: @status-declined I think most of the question he refer to are deleted.

Answer (score 10):

Here on meta we don't tolerate people who don't tolerate our memes.

Seriously, though, give it another **Weeek!** We're just about done with it.

Comment: I think you mean "give it another Eeeek!"

Comment: 6-8 more Eeeeks (to beat a dying horse)

Comment: We should totally drop that and use jQueeery! Or write a GreeeaseMonkeeey script.

Comment: people don't like to have their cheeese moved.

Comment: oh jeeeeeeesus.

Comment: I seee a new meeeme starting.

Comment: I couldn't come up with a witty comment, so just pick one at random and apply this: `comment = Regex.Replace(comment,"ee","eee");`

Comment: You know how you love your pizza and have them every day for two months? You wake up on day 61, look at a pizza and go.. nah, never again. Yeah, that's the feeling from these dead-horse flogging comments.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, because Ooook! belongs to the Librarian...

Comment: This is a terrible answer. But +1 anyways because I get it and it's Meta.