# Get notification when someone likes my comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Can we get notification or some other way of knowing if someone liked my comments.

Comment: Why? ···········

Comment: its just a request....i would just like it...for e.g. sometimes people deliberately put witty comments and would like to know how people respond to it!

Comment: The sites aren't here to float egos.

Comment: It's an upvote. **An upvote**.

Comment: @squillman why are u guys so theoretical all the time....whatever happened to the fun factor

Comment: @Suraj: See [Why isn't meta funny anymore?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75715/why-isnt-meta-funny-anymore)

Comment: @squillman: What? When did that happen?

Comment: @mmeyers Oh wait, did I forget the word "officially"?  Darn it...

Answer (score 5):

You can already see [your comment score distribution](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/99/my-comment-score-distribution) and [a list of comments sorted by score](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112711/my-comment-scores) on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). However, because **Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and explicitly *not* a social network,** I think that real-time notifications would go against Stack Overflow's *raison d'être.*

Comment: I already know about the data explorer thing, but having it real time or maybe end-of-day notification of all such miscellanous stuff would be wonderfull...Ever thought why facebook is so successful...its because of the "Like" feature in comments.

Comment: SE has a COMPLETELY different purpose than Facebook.  And if you think that "Liking" comments is what specifically made Facebook huge then you've got some rethinking to do.

Comment: @squllman, probably not all of it is becuase "Like", but for facebook "like" helps retain a lot of traffic.