# Add retro filters for code

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting

Triggered by [a question where the code was provided via a link to Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14790585/2) and by the existence of the code hosting service [Instacode](http://instacod.es/), I’d like to suggest implementing hipstery image filers for code posted on Stack Overflow:

[instacode example http://instacod.es/file/60650?.png](http://instacod.es/file/60650?.png)

**However**, it’s obviously (duh!) bad for usability to just replace the code by an image so these retro filters should be fully implemented in CSS3 transformations which are applied to code posted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This ***must*** be implemented on April 1st.

Comment: @Zoidberg Noo, then people would think it was a joke!

Comment: Pff, I liked those filters before they were cool...

Comment: Is this a Fri... what day is this?

Comment: @Josh Does it really matter? It’s always Friday somewhere.

Comment: I can't overstate the irony of being concerned with usability while applying retro film filters to text

Comment: Seriously, don't create tags like `hipster` and `instagram` on meta again (i.e. don't create frivolous tags).

Comment: @casperOne Why not? Is there a discussion of that somewhere?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, [meta is not for humor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75715/135887) and those tags would serve no other possible purpose.

Comment: @Charles Ah. I wasn’t aware of that change in policy. I usually never use meta.

Comment: What are you talking about? Of course Meta is for humour. (It ends with tags though. Tags are SERIOUS BUSINESS)

Answer (score 16):

I wrote a custom stylesheet. It works in Google Chrome and should also work in Safari.

Feel free to improve and hipsterize further (i.e. needs more filters).

```css
.prettyprint {
    color: #839496;
    background: #002b36 url(data:image/png;base64,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);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(3deg) scale(0.8);
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    text-shadow: #002b36 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-filter: sepia(0.8);
}

.prettyprint code {
    background: transparent;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', Consolas, monospace;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.prettyprint {
}

.prettyprint .pln {
  color: inherit;
}

.prettyprint .str,
.prettyprint .lit,
.prettyprint .atv {
  color: #2aa198;
}

.prettyprint .kwd {
  color: #268bd2;
}

.prettyprint .com,
.prettyprint .dec {
  color: #586e75;
  font-style: italic;
}

.prettyprint .typ {
  color: #b58900;
}

.prettyprint .pun {
  color: inherit;
}

.prettyprint .opn {
  color: inherit;
}

.prettyprint .clo {
  color: inherit;
}

.prettyprint .tag {
  color: #268bd2;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.prettyprint .atn {
  color: inherit;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot for lazy people? :)

Comment: @Benjol I don't have one at hand, but you can make one and edit the answer to include it.

Comment: Hm, you obviously didn't understand *which* lazy person I was referring to :)